# Prevent Duplicate insert in Many-to-Many relations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I Use MVC 4 anf EF Code First 5,
i have a many-to-many relation for post and tag entities,

```
public class Post : BaseEntity
{

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PostTag> Tags { get; set; }
}



public class PostTag : BaseEntity
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

with this Fluent mapping in post entity:

```
    HasMany(p => p.Tags)
        .WithMany(t => t.Posts)
        .Map(pt => pt.ToTable("PostTagsJunction")
            .MapLeftKey("PostId")
            .MapRightKey("TagId"));
```

my post service for add new post:

```
public void Add(Post entity)
{
    _posts.Add(entity);
}
```

and my problem is:
when i add new post entity with this tags:["A","B","C"]

which in database exists this tags :["B","H","E"],

but in tags entity insert new ["B"] recored, which this is duplicate!

How i must insert new post which only insert ["A","C"] tags?

i want become to this (new post id is 3):

posts:

```
postid
1
2
3
```

tags:

```
tagid   name
1       B
2       H
3       E
4       A
5       C
```

PostTagsJunction:

```
postid   tagid
1        2
1        3
2        3
2        1
3        1
3        4
3        5
```

Comment: Isn't this more of an issue in the web site, and how the information is being updated in the database (to create the dup)?  Could you then post the view and controller, if necessary?

Comment: please again see my question,that is Obvious.